# Styling thumbnails with bootstrap 3 and rails 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a rails 4 app, using bootstrap 3, and trying to create thumbnails on a subscription page that should look identical to: 
[image]

Problem is that my coloring within the thumbnails is applying behind the actual thumbnail.  I'm also having issues getting the "3 projects, 3 pages..." details at the bottom of the thumbnail to center properly.  [image]

Any direction is much appreciated.

My stylesheet:

```
ul.koudoku-pricing-table {

  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  list-style-type: none;


  li.plan {

    text-align: center;

    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    margin-top: 17px;

    margin-left: 0;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;

    &.plan-primary {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      margin-top: 0px;

      margin-left: -5px;
      margin-right: -5px;

      z-index: 100;

      h3 {
        font-size: 32.5px;
        line-height: 51px;
      }
      h4 {
        line-height: 22px;
      }
      a, input[type=submit] {
        font-size: 21.5px;
        line-height: 26px;
      }
      ul.features {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        li {
          font-size: 12pt;
        }
      }
    }

    .call-to-action {
      margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .features {
      margin: 0;
      li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 8px;
        line-height: 18px;
        vertical-align: top;
        border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
      }
      li:first-child {
        border-top: none;
      }
    }

  }


  .social-proof {
    padding: 17px 0;
    blockquote {
      h2, h3, h4 {
        padding: 5px 0;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

and the view:

```
<ul class="thumbnails koudoku-pricing-table">
  <% @plans.each do |plan| %>
    <li class="col-md-3 plan <%= 'plan-primary' if plan.highlight? %>">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3><%= plan.name %></h3>
          <h4><%= plan_price(plan) %></h4>
          <div class="call-to-action">
            <% if @subscription.nil? %>
             <% if plan.highlight? %>
              <%= link_to Koudoku.free_trial? ? 'Start Trial' : 'Sign Up', koudoku.new_subscription_path(plan: plan.id), class: "btn btn-success" %>
              <% else %>
              <%= link_to Koudoku.free_trial? ? 'Start Trial' : 'Sign Up', koudoku.new_subscription_path(plan: plan.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
              <% end %>

            <% elsif @subscription.persisted? %>
              <% if @subscription.plan == plan %>
                <%= form_for @subscription, url: owner_subscription_path(@owner, @subscription) do |f| %>
                  <%= f.submit 'Selected', class: "btn btn-large", disabled: 'disabled' %>
                <% end %>
              <% else %>
                <%= form_for @subscription, url: owner_subscription_path(@owner, @subscription) do |f| %>
                  <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id, value: plan.id %>
                  <%= f.submit @subscription.describe_difference(plan), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% else %>
              <%= link_to Koudoku.free_trial? ? 'Start Trial' : 'Upgrade', new_owner_subscription_path(@owner, plan: plan.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <ul class="features">
            <% if Koudoku.free_trial? %>
            <li class='muted'><%= Koudoku.free_trial_length %>-day Free Trial</li>
            <% end %>
            <%= BlueCloth.new(plan.features.gsub(/\n/, "\n\n")).to_html.gsub(/<(\/?)p>/, '<\1li>').html_safe %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  <% end %>

  <li class="col-md-3 social-proof">
    <%= render 'koudoku/subscriptions/social_proof' %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is plain CSS: BS3 class "thumbnail" overrides your background-color in `li.plan`, being a class of child `<div>` for `<li>`. To overcome this you need to specify background for `thumbnail`-class in stylesheet. Something like this should work:

```
.plan .thumbnail {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

OR simply

```
.thumbnail {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

if you want to override it for the whole project.